# javascript variable initialization on html page when declared in more than one place

Tags: javascript, html, variables, initialization

## oops - incorrectly posted

apologize to all.  misread my code and misinterpreted its behavior.

---

### source code

have page in which variable `shoe` is initialized twice, once in `index.html` and once in an included `script.js`:

#### index.html

```
<script src='script.js'></script>
<script>
   var shoe = { color: 'pink' };
</script>
```

#### script.js

```
var shoe = { size: 13 };
```

### resulting value

in `chrome`, the resulting value of `shoe` was

```
>> shoe = { color: 'pink', size: 13 }
```

it appears that `chrome` concatenated the two declarations - which is super cool
and super polite.

it this standard behavior?  can I count on this between browsers?

---

### runtime example

see http://www.trailsandtribulations.net/tech/barebone.html

the sources are:

- http://www.trailsandtribulations.net/tech/barebone.jade
- http://www.trailsandtribulations.net/scripts/session.js

(I have temporarily unbundled the javascript)

the variable that's declare more than once is `state`

Comment: That's weird, and in my opinion _not_ cool. I would've expected `shoe` to be `{ color: 'pink' }` because that assignment happened last. (What does Chrome do if the values aren't objects, e.g., if script.js has `shoe = 13` and index.html has `shoe = 'pink'`?)

Comment: I can't replicate this in Chrome.

Comment: what version of Chrome? I also can't replicate

Comment: @user1689607 you're right. Read the question too quickly. Thought he was just adding a property in two different locations. Will remove.

Comment: Can ***anyone*** replicate this? If not, I've a feeling we're being trolled.

Comment: @user1689607 will verify everything and post back

Comment: have verified - not to say I haven't made a mistake. adding link info to bottom of question.

Comment: If this is true, this should be referenced in a bug report to V8. **Not cool**

Comment: What happened to your `shoe` example? You have a whole lot more code there than just that. What makes you think it isn't one of those initialization function modifying the object? Did you verify this issue with your `shoe` example or not?

Comment: @user1689607 - seems you are right.  when put in bare `shoe` example, does not duplicate behavior as with `state`.  need to examine why `state` behaves the way it does - no idea at this time.  will report back as comment and update question.

Comment: @ccyoung does 'state.inited' have a value if you inspect the object in the chrome console? I suspect it doesn't and hence, the object is getting reassigned as it should.

Comment: @user1689607 - you are right - behavior as described does not occur.  apologize for leading wild goose chase.  will change question to reflect reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation in your question is actually not occurring at all (at least with version 23 of chrome). I'll attempt to show you this is the case.

First, 'var state' is declared in your 'session.js' with the follow attributes.

```
var state = {
  inited: false,
  sid: null,
  hash: null,
  status: null,
  usr: {},
  domain: window.location.hostname.split('.').splice(-2).join('.')
};
```

Then within the head of your html you have a script block that declares 'var state' again, this overwrites the original object as it should.

```
var state = {
  sources: [
    '/tech/layout.jade',
    '/scripts/bladette.js',
    '/scripts/utils.js',
    '/scripts/modal.js',
    '/scripts/session.js',
    '/scripts/outliner.js',
    '/scripts/restful.js',
    '/scripts/params.js',
    '/scripts/menu.js',
    '/scripts/checks.js',
    '/scripts/notes.js',
    '/scripts/expand.js',
    '/scripts/store.js',
    '/scripts/storage.js' ],
  initFuncs: [ session.init ]
}
```

After this, there are many places in your code where you are assigning values to your state object. This is why it starts to look like both objects were merged. **One give away that it wasn't is that 'state.inited' does not exist, yet it is declared with this property in the 'session.js' script**. Your object is getting these properties via other functions. My advice would be to debug through your JS at different stages/events and check 'state' object to work out where these values are getting added. Remembering that 'state.foo = 1;' will give the 'state' object a property of 'foo' regardless of it being declared with it or not.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

That behavior is not standard and should not be relied on.  You should do something like this:

```
var shoe = shoe || {};
shoe.color = 'pink';

var shoe = shoe || {};
shoe.size = 13;
```

Basically, this syntax assigns `shoe` to `shoe` if it is defined, otherwise it creates a new object.  This will always preserve the previous state of `shoe` if it exists and allow you to modify it safely.  Using this syntax, it does not matter if you try to initialize the variable once or ten times.  It will always be correct and behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Might be very cool that chome knew to make them a single object, but I would suggest you avoid doing that in the future.

A better practice would be to create an object similar to

```
var shoe = {
  size: 13,
  color: 'pink'
};
```

If you want to create shoe objects with different colors you could do something similar to

```
function shoe(attributes) {
   this.size = attributes.size;
   this.color = attributes.color;
}
```

now you could create a new shoe object with the following

```
var my_shoe = new shoe({
  size: 10.5,
  color: 'white'
});
```

I can now get the color of my_shoe like so:

```
my_shoe.color; // returns 'white'
```

Relying on the browser to interpret what you are trying to do is never a good idea.

Comment: Might be that it doesn't actually happen. And if it did, there would be nothing cool about it. It would be absolutely terrible.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of the variable being initialized in two places, which may be necessary if the exact page/include structure is not always known.

Comment: Initializing the same variable in two different places is 100% avoidable when done incorrectly. Initializing the same variable to different values depending on circumstances is very common though, when different values are required depending on the program state.

@user1689607. I meant that he may find it cool, but is truly not.

Answer (score -3):

var keyword is known to make the variable global within the page
That is a 'nice' feature of Chrome, but weird enough to avoid
Try to write your code with OOP concept to avoid such kind of browser dependency

Comment: For the code shown, the variable would be global without `var` too. I think the OP expected the variable to be global, but why is the browser combining the two objects instead of letting the second overwrite the first?

Comment: Uh, no. **Not** using var to declare variables makes them global. Using var declares them in function scope, which in this case happens to be global. And it's not a feature of Chrome, it's a feature of ECMAScript.

Comment: what I mean is same as tjameson, at the page level with or without var the variable is global.  Inside a function using var makes it global equiv. to the way you do window.myVar = something; this is like var myVar = something;

Comment: @Mr.Tiger: That is completely backwards. Using `var` inside a function makes it ***not*** global. Omitting `var` in a function makes it global if the variable hasn't been declared elsewhere.